# [PySpark][java.lang.StackOverflowError on df.write.csv]

Tags: java, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hdfs

I'm using PySpark version 3.1.1 on a Kubernetes cluster
I'm trying to write a spark dataframe to HDFS in csv format. Dataframe has about 2.4 million rows and 130 columns and has 5 partitions. If I reduce the data the code works fine.
Following is the code snippet:

```
engineered_df.cache()
engineered_df.count()
engineered_df = engineered_df.repartition(5)
engineered_df.write.csv(CommonConstants.HDFS_ENGINEERED_DATA_PATH, mode="overwrite")
```

And this is the stacktrace:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o3543180.csv.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:231)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:218)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:215)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.$anonfun$runCommand$1(DataFrameWriter.scala:989)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:772)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:989)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:438)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:415)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:293)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.csv(DataFrameWriter.scala:979)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task serialization failed: java.lang.StackOverflowError
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$ReplaceTable.lookup(ObjectOutputStream.java:2399)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1113)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.writeObject(List.scala:477)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor201.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
```

I have tried increasing the number of partitions.

Comment: Why do you need `repartition(5)`? If the dataset is large, partitions might get too big to fit inside one executor.

Comment: Hi, I have increased the number of partitions to 25, still getting same error.

Comment: Try with 500. If it still fails, the answer you got is a good lead but it's hard to tell without more code

Comment: Why are you caching the DataFrame? Do you need that `count` action or it was just a test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this problem will occur when your DAG is growing fast and  there's too many level of transformations happening in your code. The JVM will not be able to hold the operations to perform lazy execution when an action is performed in the end because the dag is too long, try checkpointing:

```
spark.sparkContext.setCheckpointDir("./checkpoint")
engineered_df.checkpoint()
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response, I have checkpointed the dataframe before executing the above code snippet.

Comment: Thank you for the late reply, checkpointing solved my issue, thank you so much.